# improvement of quality of calibration plots

Tags: r, math, plot, statistics

I have implemented several calibration techniques. I generate calibration plots as follows (dummy code):

```
require("caret")
x <- exp(rnorm(1000))/sum(exp(rnorm(1000))) # "calibrated prediction"
target <- rep(0:1, 1000)

df <- data.frame(target, x)
names(df) <- c("target", "prediction")
df$target <- as.factor(df$target)

cali_plot <- calibration(
  as.formula(paste("target ~ ", paste(c("x"), sep = ":", collapse =" + "), sep = "")),
  data = df, cut = 10
) # in ten bins

xyplot(cali_plot, auto.key = list(columns = 2))
jpeg(file = "somewhere/method_1/...", bg = "transparent", width = 400, height = 350)
xyplot(cali_plot, auto.key = list(columns = 2))
dev.off()
```

My problem is (do not pay attention to the graph, it is just a reproducible example) that the quality of jpg is really poor.

To change it I try to use the package `ggplot` in the following way:

```
ggplot(file = "somewhere/method_1/...", bg = "transparent", width = 400, height = 350)
```

And get an error. I simply try to improve the quality. Could you please give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the jpeg format. The jpeg format is “lossy,” meaning it retains all color information, but compress file size by selectively discarding data—and that compression can result in a loss of quality. You can lessen the amount of compression by increasing the quality argument but the jpg format is really not the best for images containing text.

Unless the jpeg format is critical for you you should use a vector-based format such as pdf

```
pdf(file = "somewhere/method_1/...")
xyplot(cali_plot, auto.key = list(columns = 2))
dev.off()
```